# I can access XML data using CURL -u and get it in the browser using HTTP Basic Auth. How do I duplicate the process in Java?

Tags: java, xml, http, authentication, recurly

```
curl -u APIKEY https://api.recurly.com/v2/accounts
```

In the terminal...
Works like a charm and gets the XML I want...

***Update:***

https://companyName.recurly.com/v2/accounts.xml
Asks for a username and password to access the xml from a browser window. I can type this in and the browser will display the xml data for me.
I just need a barebones walk through of something that gets the xml doc into my "System.out.println()" screen. I'll figure it out from there I just need to get the data on my screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for. I found it at this website...
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html. I'm so excited I finally got this to work. This works like a charm just replace "companyName" and "APIKEY" with your info.
Thanks to everybody and their input and help!

```
package getrecurly;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

/**
 *
 * @author jackcrishjr
 */
public class GetRecurly{


public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String webPage = "https://companyName.recurly.com/v2/accounts.xml";
            String name = "APIKEY";
            String password = "APIKEY";

            String authString = name + ":" + password;
            System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("*** END ***");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can HttpClient in you java code

See the link

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Answer (score 1):

I would use HttpURLConnection to get it

```
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    System.out.println("Content-Type = " + httpConn.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition"));
    System.out.println("Content-Length = " + httpConn.getContentLength());

   InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: The exception this throws is: I think it is because of the "APIkey@" before the URL. Is this possible? It seems like I'm missing something somewhere. Why does terminal allow me to grab the file but Java doesn't? ---

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://APIkey@api.recurly.com/accounts.xml
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
 at getxml.GetXML.main(GetXML.java:22)

Comment: do you usually use password? The form is usually http://username:password@example.com/something

Comment: I don't. Just the api key can get me on.